# Is it now possible to copy sonarqube false positive to a branch?

Tags: copy, sonarqube, branch, false-positive

Sonarqube allows to mark issues as false positive.
However, when analyzing a new branch, sonarqube handles this branch as independent and the false positives have to be marked again. This becomes quickly unpractical as the project grows.
It would be great if false positives could be copied to the branch project.

By searching the net, I see that the question was raised multiple time over the years (2012, 2014, [SONAR-2877](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2877) (broken), including on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514450/sonarqube-4-how-to-keep-the-false-positive-violations-during-upgrade)). But they are rather old and the answer was that it's not possible.

Is it now possible to copy sonarqube false positive to a branch ?
Do you now a "non-official" way to do it ?

Comment: Nope. Not yet. It's in the roadmap for this year.

Comment: I described one "non-official" solution in [my response to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43279845/7333940).

Comment: G.Ann Will this feature be available in the open source  or commercial version?  Also, Is there an ETA for this feature?